# Не отображаются глобальные переменные Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Можно ли как-то добавить в intellisense Visual Studio Code отображение переменных объявленных через global. ? Я так же пробовал WebStorm и там все переменные отображаются отлично.

[image: var]

[image: global]